# Regex to replace nested tokens

Tags: java, regex

I have a need to take a regex pattern and escape curly braces programatically.  The input regex will match the following patterns (with text before, after and between tags):

```
&{token1}
&{token1}&{token2}&{tokenN...}
&{token1&{token2&{tokenN...}}}
```

So far, I am fine with everything except the nested tags.  This is what I have.

```
regex = regex.replaceAll("(&)(\\{)([^{}]+)(\\})", "$1\\\\$2$3\\\\$4");
```

I have also tried to use iteration and recursion but the problem that I'm running into is that once the innermost token is escaped, it messes with the match.

I have tried negative lookbehinds, but that doesn't do what I expect.  It will only match/replace the innermost token.

```
regex = regex.replaceAll("(&)(\\{)([^(?<!\\\\{)|(?<!\\\\})]+)(\\})", "$1\\\\$2$3\\\\$4");
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Edit:  Example input/output

```
&{token1}   //input
&\{token1\} //output

&{token1}&{token2}&{tokenN...}        //input
&\{token1\}&\{token2\}&\{tokenN...\}  //output

&{token1&{token2&{tokenN...}}}        //input
&{token1&{token2&\{tokenN...\}}}      //output
&\{token1&\{token2&\{tokenN...\}\}\}  //expected output

//To throw a wrench into it, normal quantifiers should not be escaped
text{1,2}&{token1&{token2&{tokenN...}}}        //input
text{1,2}&{token1&{token2&\{tokenN...\}}}      //output
text{1,2}&\{token1&\{token2&\{tokenN...\}\}\}  //expected output
```

Edit 2: Example of what happens outside of this process: The tags will be resolved to text and then in the end, it should be a valid regex.

```
a{2}&{token1&{token2&{tokenN...}}}        //input
a{2}&\{token1&\{token2&\{tokenN...\}\}\}  //expected output of this regex
a{2}foobarbaz                             //expected output after tokens are resolved (&{token1} = foo, &{token2} = bar, &{tokenN...} = baz)
```

Comment: Can you post example input string and expected output string it is a little confusing as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Can curly braces appear in other places than tags? If not, just excape all `{` and `}` individually.

Comment: Regex mathematical model is not powerful enough to deal with counting, and Java regexp engine does not have an extension to make it powerful enough to deal with unlimited number of nested groups either. Fixed number is possible, but its readability quickly degrades to "write-only" levels. Writing a simple nesting-level-counting program will save you a lot of time.

Comment: `String.replaceAll("\\{", "\\\\{").replaceAll("\\}", "\\\\}")`?

Comment: I added examples.  Normal curly brace quantifiers should not be escaped.  That would make it too easy ;o)

Comment: @Marvin:  What you suggest is too generic.  BUT it gives me the idea to use two replaceAlls.  That may work with negative lookbehinds.  Let me do some testing - but your suggestion may be my solution.

Comment: @Marvin, I tested with two replaceAlls and it works.  If you add an answer, I'll select it as the solution.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks, but I wouldn't want to post an unfinished solution and I currently don't have time to twiddle with the lookbehinds ;) Especially since there is already a solution with only one replaceAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
regex = regex.replaceAll("(?<=&)(?=\\{)|(?<!\\{\\d{0,6},?(\\d{0,6})?)(?=\\})","\\\\");
```

where `(0,6)` determine how many digits could be there, 6 is enough I think
Java example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 0;
        String regex = "&{token1}&{token2}&{tokenN}\n" +
                "&{token1&{token2&{tokenN}}}\n" +
                "text{1,2}&{token1{1}&{token2{1,}&{tokenN{0,2}}}}\n";
        regex = regex.replaceAll("(?<=&)(?=\\{)|(?<!\\{\\d{0,6},?(\\d{0,6})?)(?=\\})","\\\\");
        System.out.println(regex);
    }
}
```

with output:

```
&\{token1\}&\{token2\}&\{tokenN\}
&\{token1&\{token2&\{tokenN\}\}\}
text{1,2}&\{token1{1}&\{token2{1,}&\{tokenN{0,2}\}\}\}
```

Comment: It could be any number of characters (though, over 1000 or more seems highly unlikely), so I can't make any assumptions.  It could contain { or } non-escaped if it follows the normal regex quantifier pattern.

Comment: oooh.  This is very interesting.  I've never seen a zero-length replacement like that.  Let me do some testing.

Comment: I altered it slightly to account for an edge case where someone would want to repeat a & that doesn't indicate a token. `(?<=&)(?=\{(?!\d{0,10},?\d{1,10}))|(?<!\{\d{0,10},?\d{1,10})(?=\})`

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid regex and create simple state machine which will store sequence of decisions about escaping of `{`. Based on this informations each time when we find `}` we can make appropriate decision to escape or unescape it and remove that last information since we don't need it anymore.

So your code can look something like

```
public static String myEscape(String text){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    char prev = '\0';
    Stack<Boolean> stack = new Stack<>();

    for (char ch : text.toCharArray()){
        if (ch == '{'){
            if (prev == '&'){
                sb.append('\\');
            }
            stack.push(prev == '&');
        }else if (ch == '}'){
            if (stack.pop()){
                sb.append('\\');
            }
        }
        sb.append(ch);
        prev = ch;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Example:

```
text{1,2}&{token1&{token2{foo}...}}
```

- we find first `{` and see that it was not preceded by `&` we place in stack `false`
- when we find `}` and based on top value from stack (false) decide that it should not be escaped
- we see another `{` and since it is preceded by `&` we place on top of stack `true`
- we find another `{` and since it is also preceded by `&` we place at top of stack another `true`
- we find another `{` which this time is not preceded by `&` so we place at top of stack `false`

So as we see stack stores informations about if we should escape next `}` or not, which currently `false -> true -> true` we can see that next `}` means that we should expect `}` `\}` `\}`.

Comment: I have a solution, but I am curious - the regex engine is a state machine itself.  Is there a reason to use a custom state machine?  I understand that performance may be impacted, but that aside, is there another reason?

Comment: @Tim Sometimes is readability, sometimes it is to make sure everything will work as we want, even when we will add more nesting, since Java regex can't handle because it doesn't support recursion. For instance your currently accepted answer for input like `text{1,2}&{token1&{token2&{tokenN{foo}...}}}` will generate `text{1,2}&\{token1&\{token2&\{tokenN{foo\}...\}\}\}` so if I understand you correctly `{foo}` should stay untouched, but we got `{foo\}`.